# Does Spring Boot's 2.3.x new Kubernetes Readiness probe consider the state of external systems out of the box? if not, how can we incluide it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-application-availability-readiness-state):

> An application is considered ready as soon as application and
>   command-line runners have been called, see Spring Boot application
>   lifecycle and related Application Events.

So it doesn't seem to be considering external systems suchs a database. Is this correct?

How could we make the `ReadinessStateHealthIndicator` evaluate the state of such systems so the pod is taken away from the k8s service load balancer when they are failing of are not available?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Comment: No, I haven't found it yet.